# When should we load the function, if we want to add a function to a prototype using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prototype

I am trying to add a toCamelCase function to the String prototype in React with TypeScript.
Here is what I did, in a *toCamelCase.d.ts* file:

```
interface String {
  toCamelCase(): string;
}

String.prototype.toCamelCase = function (): string {
  return this[0].toUpperCase() + this.slice(1).toLowerCase();
};
```

Now I am just wondering when and in which file should I load this script so I can get access to it.
I am aware that I can simply define a function and use that.
However, I am curious how to do it with prototype and what would be the downside doing things like this if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

### Where to do it?

In `main.js` or `index.js` or any other file that bootstraps your application

### What are the downsides?

You can never know if one of the libraries that you use using relies on `String.prototype` being unaltered. It can cause major issues that you will have a hard time finding.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how that could be a problem when adding methods to a prototype. I mean if the other libraries use the unaltered version of the prototype, they should be able to just use it unless there are some underlying problems I don't know of. The only thing I can think of is they are trying to alter the prototype too and there could be a name conflict. It is much appreciated if you could go into a little more details. I have searched around the question but maybe I am using wrong keywords that I could not find anything about what you have said. Thanks